# MySQL: Should I bother with collations?

Tags: mysql, collation

MySQL supports [more than 70 collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html), but how should I use them properly?

I'm always using `utf8_general_ci` because it feels general :)

But are there cases when I need other collations too? For example in a multi-lingual website or something? (what feels a bit strange because for that there are server side scripting methods).

So should I bother with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a sensible default (or just use the native database default), you can then override the default collation in a query if necessary.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html